# Similarity between complex functions and multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, complex-numbers

Are complex functions defined in multivariable form or as a singular function? For example:

$F(x)=x^2$ can be equivalently represented as $F(u,v)=(u^2-v^2,2uv)$ where $x=u+vi$. Is there a preferred form, or are they interchangeable? Additionally, does it make sense to refer to partial derivatives if complex functions are technically single variable?

Comment: A complex differentiable function is an $\mathbb{R}^2$ differentiable function that in addition satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations and vice versa. A $\mathbb{R}^2$ differentiable function that satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations is a complex differentiable function.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formulas, you can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: In a sense, *all* functions in mathematics are functions of a single variable, at least when represented in set theory. I'm not at all sure how natural this is. But it can be very convenient. In the present instance, it is convenient to "identify" complex numbers with ordered pairs of real numbers, and indeed, they are often formally defined as such. So a function of a complex variable *is* also a function of two real variables.